# MongoDB exception is not passed over Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

In My Application we use Angular as front end and MonoDB data Base 
And we are doing http call .
Without starting MongoDB Instance If I start my Server and try to access Application DB exception is not passed over Angular.On console I am getting 500 error  .
Is it fine ??
Or any other way we can display some message on Angular??

Comment: Share your server code. it's not a good practice to show just error code (500 in this case) and leave it at that. The user won't know what went wrong and you won't know what to fix if your errors are not self descriptive.

Comment: how do you connect to database? share the code

Comment: <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="${mongodb.server.host}" port="${mongodb.server.port}" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.unisys.workbench.service" />
 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
  <constructor-arg value="${mongodb.schema}" />

I am connecting trow Spring